# How to configure ActionMailer to use SendGrid's V2 API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, email, smtp, sendgrid

Authenticating with username and password will no longer be supported as of Jan 20, 2021. How can I configure my rails app to authenticate with api key? I am using Heroku.

Answer (score 4):

First, login to your SendGrid account and generate a new api key. Give it the appropriate permissions for your app. https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/api_keys

Then edit your `config/environments/production.rb` file.

From something like this:

```
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USER_NAME'],
    :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true}
```

To this:

```
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name => 'apikey',
    :password => ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'],
    :domain => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true}
```

Notice we change the user_name to 'apikey', and password to the api key stored in your environment variables.